# Списывание репутации при удалении вопроса

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-так-задумано, репутация

Не впервые замечаю, что при удалении некоторых моих вопросов, списывается репутация и в истории списание не отображается.

Например за удаление [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/201629/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-nginx) списалось **-3**.

Также заметил, что на **meta.ru.stackoverflow.com** моя репутация сохранилась, а на **ru.stackoverflow.com** списалась.

И ещё непонятно, что в этом тексте и во многих моих вопросах не отвечает стандартам. Приходится повторять текст и потом через редактирование исправлять:

[image]

Comment: Про стандарты — это просто тупой фильтр, он считает количество символов и подразумевает, что мы должны быть многословны и красноречивы.

Comment: @NickVolynkin А нельзя ли исправить это всплывающее сообщение, чтобы там прямым текстом говорилось, что нужно увеличить длину сообщения. А то я когда задавал на Мете вопрос, тоже долго мучился, чем же он не подходит.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: я поднимал этот вопрос уже достаточно давно, но пока результатов нет. Можете, например, проголосовать. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/550/181472

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov кстати, вы можете там предложить свой вариант сообщения, который будет понятно объяснять, что нужно сделать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На этом вопросе был один голос за (+5 репутации) и один голос против (-2). В сумме +3. Удаляя вопрос, вы эти самые +3 и теряете. В истории это отражается как удаление строк, в которых репутация добавлялась (т.е. заметить невозможно).

Подробнее: [«Что такое репутация? Как можно её заработать (и потерять)?»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

> Также заметил, что на meta.ru.stackoverflow.com моя репутация сохранилась, а на ru.stackoverflow.com списалась.

Репутация на Мете всегда обновляется с некоторой задержкой, это нормальная работа сайта.

---

Я тут задумался по поводу вопроса, не зря ли закрыли/удалили. Да, ответ был дан плохой, но это не делает плохим вопрос. Тем более, его можно было бы переформулировать во что-нибудь вроде "Как защитить сервер на ngnix  от DDOS-атаки?".

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Удалил не зря, потому что когда увидел его, стало как-то стыдно от того, что я когда-то мог задать такую глупость.

Comment: @ModaL: все мы растём ))